# ZODB database: table joins

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, zodb

I have been trying to find examples in ZODB documentation about doing a join of 2 or more tables. I know that this is an Object Database, but I am trying to create objects that represent tables.

And I see that ZODB makes use SQLAlchemy.

So I was wondering if I can treat things in ZODB in a relational like sense.
I hope someone can let me know if my train of thought in using this ZODB is OK, or if one has to think in very different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZODB does *not* use SQLAlchemy, and there is no relational model. There are no tables to join, period. The ZODB stores an *object tree*, there is no schema. It's just Python objects in more Python objects.

Any references to ZODB and SQLAlchemy are all for *applications built on top of the ZODB*, where transactions for *external* relational databases accessed through SQLAlchemy are tied in with the ZODB transaction manager to ensure that transactions cover both the ZODB and data in other databases. This essential means that when you commit the ZODB transaction, SQLAlchemy is told about this too.

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks for your reply. And yes, thanks for explaining how SQLAlchemy is being used here, so its not used to do any actual relational  type of manipulation, like you said its used to act as a layer between relational database to python then to ZODB. After looking at my data and organizing it, in a hierarchical way, I see there is  no need for join type of operation. Tree structures automatically eliminate the need to think in terms of joins. SO I got it.

Comment: I will choose your answer since it explains the SQLAlchemy aspect.